# Python rock,paper,scissors game not working as expected

Tags: python

I am a complete beginner with python and I was just messing around trying to create a rock, paper, scissors game, but I think I have made some mistakes as the program doesn't seem to work as expected.  After I give a value to x, it prints you lost the game; it doesn't even go through the loop.

```
print('welcome to the virtual game of rock,paper,scissors!')
print('select your move:rock,paper,scissors')
x = ''
input(x)
import random
y = random.choice(['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'])
wins = 0
loses = 0
for i in range(3):
 if x == 'rock':
     if y == 'rock':
         print('the computer used')
         print(y)
         print('draw')
         print(wins)
         print(loses)
     elif y == 'paper':
         print('the computer used')
         print(y)
         print('you lost this round')
         loses = loses+1
         print(wins)
         print(loses)
     elif y == 'scissors':
         print('the computer used')
         print(y)
         print('you won this round')
         wins = wins+1
         print(wins)
         print(loses)
 if x == 'paper':
     if y == 'rock':
         print('the computer used')
         print(y)
         print('you won this round')
         wins = wins+1
         print(wins)
         print(loses)
     elif y == 'paper':
         print('the computer used')
         print(y)
         print('draw')
         print(wins)
         print(loses)
     elif y == 'scissors':
         print('the computer used')
         print(y)
         print('you lost this round')
         loses = loses+1
         print(wins)
         print(loses)
 if x == 'scissors':
     if y == 'rock':
         print('the computer used')
         print(y)
         print('you lost this round')
         loses = loses+1
         print(wins)
         print(loses)
     elif  y == 'paper':
         print('the computer used')
         print(y)
         print('you won this round')
         wins = wins+1
         print(wins)
         print(loses)
     elif y == 'scissors':
         print('the computer used')
         print(y)
         print('draw')
         print(wins)
         print(loses)
if wins > loses:
 print('you won the game')
else:
 print('you lost the game')
```

Comment: Please reduce and enhance this into the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  "Doesn't work as expected" is not a problem specification.  Your posted code hangs waiting for test input -- it's *your* job to provide that; don't expect every one of us to create and manually type test data.

Comment: Your x value is an empty string, so no if clause gets executed. You can change the line `input(x)` to `x = input()`

Comment: Python requires proper indentation.

Answer (score 1):

Your input statement should be an assignment:

```
x = input('select your move: rock, paper, scissors')
```

There are a few other issues in your code as well. For example, y (the computers move) does not change between each round. Neither does x (the players move). Your print statements across 3 lines can be condensed into 1 line. And you probably want to use a dictionary to get the winning/losing move for a rock/paper/scissor combination instead of programming each case.

Here is a sample solution. Try to understand how it works and what changes were made before proceeding.

```
import random

moveDict = {'rock': 'paper', 'paper': 'scissors', 'scissors': 'rock'}
# A dictionary is defined with the winning move for each possible move.

print('welcome to the virtual game of rock,paper,scissors!')
wins = 0
loses = 0
for i in range(3):
    #We get a new user move and computer move for each of the three rounds we play
    x = input('select your move: rock, paper, scissors')
    y = random.choice(['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'])  
    #We check using the dictionary if the player played the winning move against a computers move      
    if moveDict[y] == x:
        print('the computer used ' + y + '. You won.')
        wins += 1
    #We check if the player played the same move as the computer
    elif y == x:
        print('the computer used ' + y + '. You tied')
    else:
        print('the computer used ' + y + '. You lost')
        loses += 1
    print('Wins: ' + str(wins) + '\nLosses: ' + str(loses))
if (wins > loses):
    print('you won the game')
elif (wins == losses):
    print('you tied')
else:
    print('you lost the game')
```

Answer (score 0):

To ead a value from the user, you need to get the result of `input` function like this

```
x = input('select your move:rock,paper,scissors: ')
```

Then as you want to play several times, you need to ask the user in the loop, and the random choice in the loop too

```
for i in range(3):
    x = input('select your move:rock,paper,scissors: ')
    y = random.choice(['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'])
    # ...
```

---

Also I'd suggest you combine some of you prints, to make the code easier to read

```
for i in range(3):
    x = input('select your move:rock,paper,scissors: ')
    y = random.choice(['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'])
    if x == 'rock':
        if y == 'rock':
            print('the computer used', y, '=> draw. Score', wins, "/", loses)
        elif y == 'paper':
            loses = loses + 1
            print('the computer used', y, '=> you lost. Score', wins, "/", loses)
        elif y == 'scissors':
            wins = wins + 1
            print('the computer used', y, '=> you won. Score', wins, "/", loses)

    elif x == 'paper':
        if y == 'rock':
            wins = wins + 1
            print('the computer used', y, '=> you won. Score', wins, "/", loses)
        elif y == 'paper':
            print('the computer used', y, '=> draw. Score', wins, "/", loses)
        elif y == 'scissors':
            loses = loses + 1
            print('the computer used', y, '=> you lost. Score', wins, "/", loses)

    elif x == 'scissors':
        if y == 'rock':
            loses = loses + 1
            print('the computer used', y, '=> you lost. Score', wins, "/", loses)
        elif y == 'paper':
            wins = wins + 1
            print('the computer used', y, '=> you won. Score', wins, "/", loses)
        elif y == 'scissors':
            print('the computer used', y, '=> draw. Score', wins, "/", loses)

    else:
        print(x, "is not a correct choice !")
```